# How to store influxdb data on an externally mounted filesystem on the host using docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to run a [TIG-stack](https://github.com/huntabyte/tig-stack.git) (Telegraph, Influxdb, Grafana) in docker conainers using docker-compose on a [Rock Pi 4](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/getting_started#get_start_specs) 4GB with external SSD drives using a [SATA HAT](https://shop.allnetchina.cn/collections/frontpage/products/penta-sata-hat-for-rock-pi-4).
Linux Distr. : Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

This was running great when mounting the volumes with the following in the docker-compose.yml, except that the data was stored on an eMMC storage chip.

```
- influxdb-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
- grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana:rw
```

**The goal of the project is to store all influxdb data on external SSD drives (data will exceed the 64GB available there..)**

Problem(s):

1. Telegraph doesn't get input from [[inputs.disk]] with errors in docker-compose output.
2. df -T -h seems to show the /var/lib/influxdb2 mounted in the influxdb container, which I don't expect. It should be configured to mount /mnt/virtual/influxDB

Questions (new to docker-compose and containers):

- Is this a correct way to set everything up or is there a better way?

starting `docker-compose up` .
From problem discription:

1. Telegraph can't get the disk info, breaking the telegraph monitoring in influxDB.
2. the storage folders do not seem to be set correctly (they keep pointing to `/var/lib/influxdb2/`).

```
influxdb_1  | ts=2023-03-27T21:51:53.637652Z lvl=info msg="Resources opened" log_id=0gqGkB5l000 service=bolt path=/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt
influxdb_1  | ts=2023-03-27T21:51:53.638193Z lvl=info msg="Resources opened" log_id=0gqGkB5l000 service=sqlite path=/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.sqlite

telegraf_1  | 2023-03-27T22:16:55Z W! [inputs.diskio] Error gathering disk info: no such file or directory
```

telegraph.cong file (inputs.disk part):

```
# Read metrics about disk usage by mount point
[[inputs.disk]]
  ## By default stats will be gathered for all mount points.
  ## Set mount_points will restrict the stats to only the specified mount points.
  mount_points = ["/mnt/hdd5tb", "/mnt/virtual", "/etc/hosts"]

  ## Ignore mount points by filesystem type.
  #ignore_fs = ["tmpfs", "devtmpfs", "devfs", "iso9660", "overlay", "aufs", "squashfs"]
```

The drive(s) are mounted using mergerfs virtual storage. It's seen as a single virtual disk in the host:

```
rock@rockpi4c:~/tig-stack$ df -T -h
Filesystem     Type           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p5 ext4            57G  6.5G   48G  13% /
mergerfsPool   fuse.mergerfs  468G   26G  418G   6% /mnt/virtual
/dev/sda       ext3           117G   26G   86G  23% /mnt/sda
/dev/sdb       ext3           117G   61M  111G   1% /mnt/sdb
/dev/sde       ext4           4.6T  501G  3.8T  12% /mnt/hdd5tb
tmpfs          tmpfs          382M     0  382M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I have been able to mount the disk in a volume in the influxdb container:

```
rock@rockpi4c:~/tig-stack$ docker exec -it fd73b72ebfde bash
bash-5.1$ df -T -h
Filesystem           Type            Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on

/dev/mmcblk1p5       ext4           56.2G      6.5G     47.4G  12% /etc/influxdb2

mergerfsPool         fuse.mergerfs 467.5G     25.7G    418.0G   6% /mnt/virtual/influxDB
/dev/mmcblk1p5       ext4           56.2G      6.5G     47.4G  12% /var/lib/influxdb2
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file (volumes commented out of what I have tried so far):

```
version: "3"

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.6-alpine
    volumes:
      # - influxdb-ssd-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
      - influxdb-ssd-storage:/mnt/virtual/influxDB:rw

      # - influxdb-storage:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
      # - /mnt/virtual/influxDB:/var/lib/influxdb2:rw
      # - /mnt/virtual/influxDB:/mnt/virtual/influxDB:rw
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
    restart: unless-stopped 
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT}:8086
    user: influxdb


  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:1.25
    volumes:
      - ${TELEGRAF_CFG_PATH}:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf:rw
      # mount the external drives as read only to monitor their usage
      - /mnt/virtual:/mnt/virtual:ro
      - /mnt/hdd5tb:/mnt/hdd5tb:ro
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: unless-stopped 
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    # user: "1000"

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-oss:8.4.3
    volumes:
      - grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana:rw
      # - grafana-ssd-storage:/var/lib/grafana:rw
      # - /mnt/virtual/influxDB:/var/lib/grafana:rw
    restart: unless-stopped 
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    ports:
      - ${GRAFANA_PORT}:3000
    # user: "1000"
    user: "0:0"

# using a bind mount to use external SSD storage 
volumes:
  influxdb-ssd-storage:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /mnt/virtual/influxDB
      o: bind
  grafana-storage:
```

The .env file with environment variables:

```
DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup

# https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.6/reference/config-options/#engine-path
# Path to persistent storage engine files where InfluxDB stores all Time-Structure Merge Tree (TSM) data on disk.
DOCKER_INFLUXD_ASSET_PATH=/mnt/virtual/influxDB
DOCKER_INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH=/mnt/virtual/influxDB/influxd.bolt
DOCKER_INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH=/mnt/virtual/influxDB/engine
# DOCKER_INFLUXD_ASSET_PATH=/var/lib/influxdb2
# DOCKER_INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH=/var/lib/influxdb2/influxd.bolt
# DOCKER_INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine

# InfluxDB port & hostname definitions
#
DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT=8086 
DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_HOST=influxdb 

# Telegraf configuration file
# 
# Will be mounted to container and used as telegraf configuration
TELEGRAF_CFG_PATH=./telegraf/telegraf.conf

# Grafana port definition
GRAFANA_PORT=3000
```

The entrypoint.sh file with the influxdb setup:

```
# Ensures environment variables are set
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_RETENTION=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_RETENTION
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PORT
export DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_HOST=$DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_HOST
export DOCKER_CACHE_SNAPSHOT_WRITE_COLD_DURATION=$DOCKER_CACHE_SNAPSHOT_WRITE_COLD_DURATION
export DOCKER_INFLUXD_ASSET_PATH=$DOCKER_INFLUXD_ASSET_PATH
export DOCKER_INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH=$DOCKER_INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH
export DOCKER_INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH=$DOCKER_INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH

# Conducts initial InfluxDB using the CLI
influx setup --skip-verify --bucket ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET} \
  --retention ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_RETENTION} \
  --token ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ADMIN_TOKEN} \
  --org ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG} \
  --username ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME} \
  --password ${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD} \
  --host http://${DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_HOST}:8086 \
  --storage-cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration= ${DOCKER_CACHE_SNAPSHOT_WRITE_COLD_DURATION} \
  --assets-path= ${DOCKER_INFLUXD_ASSET_PATH} \
  --engine-path= ${DOCKER_INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH} \
  --bolt-path= ${DOCKER_INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH} \
  --force
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with using mergerFS.
InfluxDB uses mmap for the boltDB database which can't be used in certain configurations.

https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs#tips--notes --> "Shared mmap is not currently supported in FUSE w/ page caching disabled."

Mounting the volume on the host and keeping the storage path default, worked. All the data is stored on the external drives now.